# php file upload to a database

Tags: php, mysql, upload

[image]I am trying to upload a file to a directory and store its value in the database.I don't know what is wrong with this code.Thanks in advance for the help 
The pic displays variables whn echoed      .

```
$con=connect();
    $file_name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_size=$_FILES['file']['size']/1024;
    $display_name=$_POST['display_name'];

    $upload_dir='../uploads/docs/';
    $file_temp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_path=$upload_dir.$file_name;
if(move_uploaded_file($file_temp,$file_path))
        {
            if($con)
            {
            $query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into dcument_upload 
            values(null,'$display_name','$file_path','$file_size')");
            $rr=mysqli_num_rows($query);
            if($rr)
                {
                    echo 'Uploaded';
                    echo $rr;
                }else
                {
                    echo "Upload failed";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                die("Cannot Connect");

            }
        }   
        else
        {
            echo "<br>Upload Failed<br>Try Again!";
        }
```

Comment: What is the output when this file is run? IE: Does it output one of your warnings/error messages, or is there any PHP errors?

Comment: Use [mysqli_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) to check number of affected rows by insert query

Comment: Have you got any error???Explain what is not working ??

Comment: File is getting uploaded to the server but i cannot insert file info into database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You were placing variables under single quotes.

```
<?php
    $con = connect();
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size']/1024;
    $display_name = $_POST['display_name'];

    $upload_dir = '../uploads/docs/';
    $file_temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_path = $upload_dir.$file_name;

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_temp,$file_path)) {
        if($con) {
            $query = mysqli_query($con,"insert into dcument_upload values(null, ".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $display_name).", ".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $file_path).", ".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $file_size)".)");
            $rr = mysqli_num_rows($query);

            if($rr) {
                echo 'Uploaded';
                echo $rr;
            } else {
                echo "Upload failed";
            }
        } else {
            die("Cannot Connect");
        }

    } else {
        echo "<br>Upload Failed<br>Try Again!";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the content of the file first:

```
$file_data = file_get_contents($file_path);
$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `dcument_upload ` VALUES (null, '". mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $display_name)."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $file_data). "', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $file_size)."')");
```

Also, use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) to escape special characters to help prevent against SQL injection.

Comment: i have stored file info in separate variables.I am not inserting them directly